# How to do a table association query to return all elements and perform further manipulation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a one to many association between Challenge (1) and Entry (many).

I would like to extract the last (as in date created) entry for each challenge and also the name of the challenge in one object.

I then use the result of the query in the view as follows:

```
                                <% @discovers.each do |discover| %>
                                        <div id="box-3" class="box">
                                        <%= link_to(image_tag(discover.picture.url), entries_path(challenge_id: discover.challenge_id),remote: true) if discover.picture? %>
                                        <span class="caption simple-caption">
                                        <p><%= discover.blob %></p>
                                        <%= link_to "Join up", join_challenge_path(id: discover.challenge_id) %>
                                        </span>
                                        </div>
                                <% end %>
```

so far I have

```
@discovers = Challenge.all.map{|c| c.entries.last}
```

but I can't then access the name of a challenge, only the records in the Entry table. How can I access both in @discovers?

#### Update

Using @rob and @Pavan's code here is what I have

view

```
                            <% @discovers.each do |discover| %>
                                <% discover.each do |disc| %>
                                        <div id="box-3" class="box">
                                        <%= link_to(image_tag(disc.picture.url), entries_path(challenge_id: disc.challenge_id),remote: true) if disc.picture? %>
                                        <span class="caption simple-caption">
                                        <p><%= disc.rules %></p>
                                        <%= link_to "Join up", join_challenge_path(id: disc.challenge_id) %>
                                        </span>
                                        </div>
                                <% end %>
                         <% end %>
```

controller

```
def index
  @discovers = Challenge.includes(:entries).collect{|c| [c.name, c.entries.last] }
  end
```

Comment: Try `@discovers = Challenge.all.map{|c| [c.name, c.entries.last] }` or `@discovers = Challenge.all.collect{|c| [c.name, c.entries.last] }`

Comment: But that will trigger you many ***DB*** calls.

Comment: @Pavan `@discovers = Challenge.includes(:entries).collect{|c| [c.name, c.entries.last] }` will perform 2 queries instead many

Comment: @rob Yes! Perfect :)

Comment: I get an error in that the loop I do subsequently on the returned query. I think its to do with the difference between what I'm returning which is for example.... , #<Entry id: 10, blob: "Its a photo ", created_at: "2015-07-26 21:51:07", updated_at: "2015-07-26 21:51:07", challenge_id: 5, picture: "Screen_Shot_2015-07-22_at_19.02.21.png">] and what @rob is returning which is ["Photo", #<Entry id: 10, blob: "Its a photo", created_at: "2015-07-26 21:51:07", updated_at: "2015-07-26 21:51:07", challenge_id: 5, picture: "Screen_Shot_2015-07-22_at_19.02.21.png">]]

Comment: @SebastianZeki which error you got?

Comment: Hi rob I've updated the code. I get the error in the loop I subsequently use as above. It says "undefined method `picture?' for #<Array:0x0000000726f848>" which I think means it can't read the array as is.

Comment: You need to iterate `discover` further. Put `<% discover.each do |disc| %>` after `<% @discovers.each do |discover| %>` and change `discover` to `disc` in the rest of the code.

Comment: I still get the same error. Not sure why. I've put the updated code in the question

Comment: I think the problem is that the first loop extracts the first part of the array only, and then the second loop has nothing really to work on. How to sort?